# Google Maps api: Show nearby Locations among array of Locations within specific radius from center point

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I want to show map with the markers of the nearby locations among the provided array of locations from the given radius.

This is my current code:

```
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map,

            draggable:true
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
```

I want to modify it so that it can show nearest locations from given center point but within specific radius. And searched locations must be within the array of locations.

Thanks for reading my question.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: [Example that finds 3 closest locations to the geocoded result](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlacesDirections.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Its useful to me. I have question about this. How can I show radius limit? It should show locations within specific radius from center point. For example 1000 meter from center point.